# Template class specialization with default value for member variables and methods

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct DefaultPattern {
  using type = int;
  static int CalculateValue(const T& input) {
    return 0;
  }
};
```

For each type `T`, I will have a specialization. The problem is that in the specialization class, I need to define all the member variables and methods that are defined in the `DefaultPattern`, even though it is possible that they have the same value as the one in `DefaultPattern`. Here is an example:

```
// A specialization for int.
template<>
struct DefaultPattern<int> {
  // Same as DefaultPattern but I need to define it again.
  using type = int;
  static int CalculateValue(const int& input) {
    return input + 2;
  }
};
```

Is there a way so that when I do the specialization, I only need to define 
those members that are different from `DefaultPattern`?

Comment: Unrelated, but why `using type = int;` ? You never use `type` anywhere.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It makes it easy to know the type given in situations like `decltype(foo)::type;` or other cases where the template argument isn't immediately obvious. Like how `std::vector<T>::value_type` is always `T`.

Comment: It is just an example that I simplified from real code. I can call DefaultPattern<int>::type or DefaultPattern<double>::type from another class. The variable type does not need to be the T we specialized.

Comment: The specialization is a separate type, so doesn't "inherit" anything. You *could* have a common base class containing things that are always the same.

Comment: Looks like it's a job for [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way so that when I do the specialization, I only need to define those members that are different from DefaultPattern?

A possible solution is a sort of self-inheritance: your specialization can inherit form the generic template. Note that to inherit from the generic template, the specilization uses a particular instantiation (e.g. `T = long` is used below).

For example:

```
template <>
struct DefaultPattern<int> : public DefaultPattern<long>
 {
   static int CalculateValue (int const & input)
    { return input + 2; }
 };
```

So `DefaultPattern<int>` inherit `type = int` from `DefaulPattern<long>` (or `DefaultPattern<std::string>` or something else) and redefine `CalculateValue()`

The following is a full working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct DefaultPattern
 {
   using type = int;

   static int CalculateValue (T const &)
    { return 0; }
 };

template <>
struct DefaultPattern<int> : public DefaultPattern<long>
 {
   static int CalculateValue (int const & input)
    { return input + 2; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same<DefaultPattern<int>::type, int>{}, "!" );

   std::cout << DefaultPattern<long>::CalculateValue(1L) << std::endl;
   std::cout << DefaultPattern<int>::CalculateValue(1) << std::endl;
 }
```